# Netplan inconsistent indentation Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: netplan, network-bridge, network-bonding, tagging, vlan

I am having an inconsistent indentation problem in a netplan configuration. I would like, if possible, someone to explain to me where I'm going wrong.
Thank you.

The error is:

```
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:**46**:12: Invalid YAML: inconsistent indentation:
           addresses: []
```

From this line until the end of the last two VLAN configurations (eno3.220 and eno3.230), is all considered as an error.

The netplan configuration is as follows:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            {}
        eno2:
            {}
        eno3:
            {}
        eno4:
            {}

    bonds:
        bond0:
            interfaces: [eno1, eno2]
            addresses: []
            parameters:
                mode: balance-alb
                mii-monitor-interval: 1
                gratuitious-arp: 5
                primary: eno1
            optional: false
    vlans:
        bond0.640:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: false
            id: 640
            link: bond0
        bond0.1008:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: false
            id: 1008
            link: bond0
        eno3.220:
           addresses: [] «-- **line 46**
           dhcp4: false 
           id: 220
           link: eno3
        eno3.230:
           addresses: []
           dhcp4: false
           id: 230
           link: eno3

    bridges:
        br0:
          interfaces: [bond0.1008]
          addresses: [ x.x.x.x/x ]
          dhcp4: false
          gateway4: x.x.x.1
          parameters:
              forward-delay: 0
          nameservers:
              addresses: [ x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y ]
              search: []
          optional: false
        br1:
          interfaces: [bond0.640]   «--- inactive at this moment
          #addresses: [ ]
          dhcp4: false
          #gateway4:
          parameters:
              forward-delay: 0
          #nameservers:
              #addresses: [ ]
              search: []
          optional: false
        br2:
          interfaces: [eno3.220]
          dhcp4: false
          addresses: [x.x.x.x/x]
          gateway4: x.x.x.1
          parameters:
              forward-delay: 0
          nameservers:
              addresses: [x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y]
              search: []
          optional: false
        br3:
          interfaces: [eno3.230] «-- inactive at this moment
          #addresses: []
          dhcp4: false
          #gateway4:
          parameters:
              forward-delay: 0
          #nameservers:
               #addresses: []
               #search: []
          optional: false
```

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: there's a lot in this yaml that is unnecessary, and therefore increases the risk of errors. `addresses: []` is default and therefore does not need to be declared. `dhcp4: false` is default and therefore does not need to be declared. @heynema's answer provides good guidance, but cleaning this file up to remove the excess will also go a long way towards eliminating syntax errors.

Comment: Updated my answer with .yaml code that passes lint.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

You have numerous .yaml errors... netplan is very fussy about spacing, indentation (should be only 2 spaces), no tabs...

Note: Install `yamllint` to check .yaml files.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install yamllint`

Here are the current errors... but there are actually more... start with changing all indentation to 2 spaces, remove extra spaces in brackets, change comments to "* comment"...

```
  35:12     error    wrong indentation: expected 12 but found 11  (indentation)
  36:24     error    trailing spaces  (trailing-spaces)
  40:12     error    wrong indentation: expected 12 but found 11  (indentation)
  47:11     error    wrong indentation: expected 12 but found 10  (indentation)
  48:23     error    too many spaces inside brackets  (brackets)
  35:26     error    syntax error: expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>' (syntax)
  48:33     error    too many spaces inside brackets  (brackets)
  54:27     error    too many spaces inside brackets  (brackets)
  54:44     error    too many spaces inside brackets  (brackets)
  58:11     error    wrong indentation: expected 12 but found 10  (indentation)
  59:12     warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
  61:12     warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
  64:12     warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
  64:11     warning  comment not indented like content  (comments-indentation)
  65:16     warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
  69:11     error    wrong indentation: expected 12 but found 10  (indentation)
  80:11     error    wrong indentation: expected 12 but found 10  (indentation)
  81:12     warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
  83:12     warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
  86:12     warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
  87:17     warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
  87:16     warning  comment not indented like content  (comments-indentation)
  88:17     warning  missing starting space in comment  (comments)
```

---

This .yaml code passes lint...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      match:
        macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    eno2:
      match:
        macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    eno3:
      match:
        macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    eno4:
      match:
        macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [eno1, eno2]
      parameters:
        mode: balance-alb
        mii-monitor-interval: 1
        gratuitious-arp: 5
        primary: eno1
  vlans:
    bond0.640:
      id: 640
      link: bond0
    bond0.1008:
      id: 1008
      link: bond0
    eno3.220:
      id: 220
      link: eno3
    eno3.230:
      id: 230
      link: eno3
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [bond0.1008]
      addresses: [x.x.x.x/x]
      gateway4: x.x.x.1
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
      nameservers:
        addresses: [x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y]
    br1:
      interfaces: [bond0.640]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
    br2:
      interfaces: [eno3.220]
      addresses: [x.x.x.x/x]
      gateway4: x.x.x.1
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
      nameservers:
        addresses: [x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y]
    br3:
      interfaces: [eno3.230]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
```

Note: See https://netplan.io/examples/

Comment: Spaces in brackets are not a yaml error.